Is it possible to calculate effect size from the relative pre-post change?
I am trying to conduct a meta-analysis that focuses on the pre-post change of an intervention. While most studies reported the pre and post mean and SD scores of the outcome, some only reported the relative and/or normalized mean and SD of the outcome. i.e. One study presented the baseline mean as 0 and the relative change is +2% with an unclear p value (i.e. p<0.05), is it still possible to get the effect size from this type of data presentation? Or should I just exclude this type of data?
Thank you for your advice.

You can meta-analyze separately or use the ratio of means (https://effectivehealthcare.ahrq.gov/sites/default/files/pdf/continuous-outcomes-quantitative-synthesis_methods.pdf) so that they are all on a percentage change from baseline.
